# Sass error with sass map Error: expected ";"

Tags: sass

Using sass maps, I have the following code which I think is correct. However I get the error Deleted css/main.css. Error: expected ";". Why is this, why did it delete my main.css file. I use sass --watch sass/main.scss:css/main.css to compile the sass to css.

```
           $colors: ( sexy: #FA6ACC, glamour: #F02A52, sky: #09A6E4);
           body {
           background-color: background-color: map-get($colors, sky);
           }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error, you define `background-color:` twice as you can see.

```
$colors: ( sexy: #FA6ACC, glamour: #F02A52, sky: #09A6E4);
       body {
       background-color: background-color: map-get($colors, sky);
       }
```

remove duplicate `background-color:` and it would be just fine

```
$colors: ( sexy: #FA6ACC, glamour: #F02A52, sky: #09A6E4);
           body {
           background-color: map-get($colors, sky);
           }
```

an example: https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/08c641e03727c09ff52fa60c9f629ee0